# Binding a label to a header in Devexpress

Tags: devexpress

Can I bind a label control in the header of Devexpress?. The label control populates dynamically.

TU

Comment: what platform? would you share code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can bind the label control to header of Devexpress by making use of Templates.

The format should be somewhat like the below:

<Template>
<Header>
//your definition of label goes here
</Header>
</Template>
```